# EXEC Stored Procedure Output to Variable in Insert Operation

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I have the following Stored Procedure:

```
Create Procedure spValueInsert
(@Param3 varchar(50) OUTPUT)
AS
BEGIN
     SELECT TOP 1 uID FROM Table2
END
```

Then in another Stored Procedure, I have the following syntax:

```
Create Procedure spMainProc
(@Col1 varchar(50), @Col2 varchar(50))
AS
BEGIN
     INSERT INTO TABLE1(Col1, Col2, Col3)VALUES(@Col1, @Col2, XXX)
END
```

For `Col3`, I want to add the result from `spValueInsert`. How can I do that?
I am trying the following syntax but it doesn't work.

```
DECLARE @OutputParameter varchar(50), @ReturnValue int
EXEC @ReturnValue = spValueInsert @OutputParameter OUTPUT
INSERT INTO Table1(Col1, Col2, Col3)VALUES (@Col1, @Col2, @OutputParameter)
```

Please advise. The data type for result is `VARCHAR(50)`.
Thank you.

Comment: From where the parameters `@Col1, @Col2` comes from since you didn't declare them? Is the column in the target table `IDENETITY`? Have you search from `scope_identity()` and _table valued parameters_?

Comment: The procedure `spValueInsert` does not have any parameters, so `EXEC @ReturnValue = spValueInsert @OutputParameter OUTPUT` is simply wrong

Comment: @Ilyes , I edit the question.

Comment: @Zhorov, I edit the question.

Comment: your first stored procedure `spValueInsert` does not even assign value to the output parameter `Param3` at all. And `TOP` should comes with a `ORDER BY`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to assign a value to the output parameter in the first procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spValueInsert (
   @uID varchar(50) OUTPUT
)
AS
BEGIN
     SELECT TOP 1 @uID = uID 
     FROM Table2
     -- ORDER BY uID
END

CREATE PROCEDURE spMainProc (
   @Col1 varchar(50), 
   @Col2 varchar(50)
)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE 
        @uID varchar(50), 
        @ReturnValue int
    EXEC @ReturnValue = spValueInsert @uID OUTPUT
    IF @ReturnValue <> 0 RETURN @ReturnValue

    INSERT INTO Table1(Col1, Col2, Col3)
    VALUES (@Col1, @Col2, @uID)
END
```

Note, that even without `SELECT TOP 1 @uID = uID ...`, the value of the output parameter will be `NULL`.

Comment: `spValueInsert ` never return a value at all, `@ReturnValue` will always be `0`

Comment: @Squirrel You are right, in this case `IF @ReturnValue <> 0 RETURN @ReturnValue` is not necessary. But I usually use some basic error handling, so checking the result from each procedure execution is just a habit.